# How to make all filetypes open in a certain program?

Tags: mime-type, file-association

I want every filetype to open in Leafpad.

I tried to edit `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to associate file types.
But I want *all* filetypes to open in a certain program, with maybe something like `\*/*=leafpad.desktop`

How to do it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you please add more information?

Comment: I want use a program for any file type

Comment: "Every file all open" - for me sound contradictory.

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense.  One program to open all file types by default.  Open .mp3, .jpg, .c, .ods for example in the same program.  There isn't a program that understands all the file formats.  The only program that could handle all formats is a hex editor/viewer and I don't see why you want to do this.  Or am I "barking up the wrong tree" here?  Have I misunderstood the question? If I have please edit the question to make it clear what you want to do and why?

Comment: yes, i want to use text-editor and hex-viewer to open all file types

Answer (score 1):

One method could be to go to **System settings** > **Details** > **Default applications**:

[image]

Another method can be to right click on the file that you want to associate with a program and select **Open with** (> **Other application...**) or select **Properties** > **Open with**  tab (I think this is the best option) and the rest is pretty self-explanatory. If you, for example, set one MP3 to be opened by the program VLC, then all MP3s would be opened by VLC when double-clicked.

And finally (but not the last one), and, in fact, this I think is what you are looking, another method could be to use **[assoGiate](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/) program** - a file types editor. To install it from [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), use next command:

```
sudo apt-get install assogiate
```

[image: assoGiate]

Comment: I want not associate for some file type, i want to associate only one program for every file

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. It's like "I want to associate a word for every grain of sand", sincerely.

Comment: @Sieuvocmaytinh Then make that clear! Your question is totally unclear. I edited your question now to clarify.

Comment: i want to use text-editor and hex-viewer to open all file types

Comment: @Sieuvocmaytinh *"Another method can be to right click on the file that you want to associate with a program and select Open with (> Other application...) or select Properties > Open with tab"*. And I think hex-viewer is a windows based program.

Comment: Note that until an application is bound, Properties will *not show* the "Open with" tab. In this case, do right-click > Open with... then select an application instead and from here, you can use either method.

Also, assoGiate seems discontinued, I cannot find the package, nor info about it on the developer's website. Too bad, it would be very helpful to generate the MIME type too! I had to do this manually following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564888/133940

Answer (score 1):

For me, with gnome applications like Dolphin, editing my `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` under the  `[Default Applications]` section I added `application/octet-stream=ghex.desktop;`

GHex is now an option with unassocated and "Open With" for associated files.

Alternatively on a global scale I edited the ghex .desktop file `/usr/share/applications/ghex.desktop` as root/sudo to add the line `MimeType=application/octet-stream;` anywhere (at the end)

I, too, thought `*/*` should have worked but it doesn't.